# Price Response Function vs Willingness to Pay vs Price Response Function

Tags: microeconomics, supply-and-demand

I'm confused on three different economics terms and seek clarification. The terms are "Demand Curve, "Price Response Function", and "Willingness to Pay".

I had thought that the demand curve was a classic sigmoid function where the X-axis represents price and the Y-axis represents probability of an arbitrary consumer purchasing the product.

Yet, when I dug into the demand curve, I saw something different. The Y-axis represented the price, and the X-axis represented the number of units demanded.

Could someone clarify what each of these terms mean mathematically and where did I go right/wrong?

Comment: 2. These are somewhat basic concepts with pretty decent explanations in textbooks and also online - I am not sure where you got the sigmoid idea from. Did you try to do some research on your own? Where did you look?

Comment: My previous role, we did pricing experiments where we’d show different prices to different customers (assumed to be drawn from the same population) and captured whether they bought/didn’t buy the product. Logistic regression gave us probability of purchase. I always thought of this as the demand curve; guess that’s a much different concept.

Comment: Well, your sigmoid function will be decreasing in log(price). If you rescale to price, multiply by the number of (identical) consumers and exchange the axes, then you get a classical demand function, at least assuming consumers with unit demand.

Comment: My mistake, I mistranslated price response function. It is in fact related to the demand function, so it is fine to keep these in one question. But again, these are fairly basic concepts with a lot of online resources explaining them. What did you look at so far?